# Arules returning empty LHS

Tags: r, arules

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
"user.get","search_restaurants","cuisines.get"
"user.get","search_restaurants","user.get","search_restaurants"
"order/address/get_user_addresses"
"search_restaurants","search_restaurantssearch_restaurants"
"restaurant.get","search_restaurants","order/menu","restaurant.get","restaurant.get","restaurant.get","order/menu","order/menu","restaurant.get","restaurant.getsearch_restaurantsrestaurant.get","user.get","order/menu","order/menu","get_user_reviews_filtered","order/menu","restaurant.get"
```

When I run the apriori algorithm on it:

```
txn1 = read.transactions(file="path", rm.duplicates=TRUE)
basket_rules <- apriori(txn1, parameter = list(sup = 0.01, conf = 0.01,target="rules"))
inspect(basket_rules)
```

I get blank lhs's. which are:

`{}            => {cuisines.get}`, etc

Any idea why this might be happening? An how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `help("apriori")`:

> The default value in `APparameter` for `minlen` is `1`. This means that
>   rules with only one item (i.e., an empty antecedent/LHS) like
>
> ```
> {} => {beer}
> ```
>
> will be created. These rules mean that no matter what other items are
>   involved the item in the RHS will appear with the probability given by
>   the rule's confidence (which equals the support). If you want to avoid
>   these rules then use the argument `parameter=list(minlen=2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by luke is correct.
In addition, we can say that apriori always gives us information about the consequent which is RHS in the program. That's why for a single item set having min support equal to min confidence is also given in the resulting output if no 'minlen' is used.

Eg.

```
  > inspect(rules)
    lhs            rhs     support confidence lift count
[1] {}          => {Soup}  0.8     0.8        1.0  4    
[2] {}          => {Pasta} 0.8     0.8        1.0  4    
[3] {Salad}     => {Ham}   0.4     1.0        1.7  2
```

I hope this explains the output(other rules are not shown in this example).
The above given is the partial output of this table.

```
Customer ID       Food 
 1          -Salad, Hamburger, Taco  
 2          -Soup, Hamburger, Pasta 
 3          -Salad, Soup, Hamburger, Pasta 
 4          -Soup, Pasta 
 5          -Taco, Pasta, Soup
```