# read.transactions for arules in R gives output of {} => {Product ID's}

Tags: r, csv, transactions, arules

As stated in the title, I am attempting to get association rules for a dataset I am working with.

Unfortunately, the output is 388 rules likes this:

```
#     lhs     rhs          support      confidence   lift
#[1]   {}  => {2760500500} 0.0005037281 0.0005037281 1   
#[2]   {}  => {2638361901} 0.0005037281 0.0005037281 1   
#[3]   {}  => {2810128001} 0.0005037281 0.0005037281 1   
#[4]   {}  => {2217240500} 0.0005084802 0.0005084802 1
```

Is this a problem with the code or possibly the dataset I am using? Thanks.

EDIT: in the read.transactions function I used the parameter = list(minlen=2) to prevent this for future reference.

Comment: Please show the code you're using.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989673/arules-returning-empty-lhs) might help.